# Accessing external function using function pointer in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, extern, undeclared-identifier

Im trying to link to a extern function using a pointer to it. But everytime I try, I get compiler errors that the extern function is undeclared. I have little experience with external functions, and so cannot see my mistake. I have a function declared in lcd.c, which I am trying to get to from a seperate file memory.c.

I need to use function pointers as I am writing an emulator, and I have a array of memory address where each element of the array links to the hardware function called if that memory address is accessed. Basically allowing me to do:

```
    UINT8 WriteMem(int address, UINT8 data) {
      return memory[address](data);
    }
```

Heres my code im having problems with:

lcd.c

```
    UINT8 LCD_dataline_R(UINT8 data) {
      // Some code
      return aValue;
    }
```

lcd.h

```
    extern UINT8 LCD_dataline_R(UINT8 data);
```

memory.c

```
    #include "lcd.h"
    typedef UINT8 (*MemFunct)(UINT8 data);
    MemFunct ReadDataLine = LCD_dataline_R;
    .
    .
    UINT8 recieved = ReadDataLine(0x80);
```

I'm compiling the code using GCC on Linux Mint

and get the error

```
    Running command: make -f makefile memory.o
    gcc -c -Wall memory.c
    memory.c:3:25: error: ‘LCD_dataline_R’ undeclared here (not in a function)
```

---

Edit

Heres the makefile:

```
    CC=gcc
    CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c99 `sdl-config --cflags` `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`
    LIBS=`sdl-config --libs` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`

    all: psiora clean

    memory.o: memory.c psiora.c lcd.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^

    clean:
        rm -rf *o psiora
```

Im only trying to compile memory.o at the moment so I've cut it down to just that part

Comment: Show your `makefile` please.

Comment: You do not need to explicitly use `extern`.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yes that's true , by default all functions are extern, but there should be no problem, by explicitly declaring functions as extern

Comment: Please show [self-contained compilable code](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: what if you try lcd.h instead of lcd.c in memory.o?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you look at the preprocessed version of `memory.c` (`gcc -E memory.c`) that the declaration of `LCD_dataline_R` from `lcd.h` is missing. Most likely this is caused by some `#if`, `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` in `lcd.h`.

Comment: I did this, and it turns out this was the problem. I did indeed have some preprocessor code where I had misspelled LCD, as LDC in one of my #ifdef. Can't believe it was such a simple mistake. Everything works fine now. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your program, but here is an example of a situation that may reproduce a similar error.

```
foo.h:
extern void foo(int a);

foo.c:
#include "foo.h"
void foo(int a)
{    
}

bar.c:
//#include "foo.h"  --> Uncomment to remove error
typedef void(*fptr)(int a);
fptr fooptr=foo;
```

On compiling,

gcc -c foo.c bar.c

i get a similar error:

```
bar.c:3: error: 'foo' undeclared here (not in a function)
```